# HTTPS recording in jmeter 2.11

Tags: https, jmeter

I am facing certificate error when recording HTTP(S) request in jmeter 2.11.

For testing purpose i am using https://www.yahoo.com but the moment i access the URL after starting proxy server,i get the certification error on webpage.

I have installed the jmeter Root-CA certificate multiple times but still no success.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try recording your script using [JMeter Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) which is capable of recording and exporting JMeter .jmx files right from Google Chrome browser without needing to worry about proxies, certificates, cookies, headers, etc.

N.B. However I'm able to record calls to yahoo.com using HTTPS in my environment (JMeter 2.11 r1554548, Firefox 29.0.1, Java 1.7.0_45, OpenSuSE 13.1 x64).

Comment: i don't want to move to chrome extension. I need to record it using jmeter. Please let me know if i am doing something wrong

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser data? Press `Ctrl+Shift+Del` and remove **everything** and restart your recording.